# SSRS 2008 - Uniform Chart Legends for multi-chart report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Okay, I have a report with multiple charts in it.  I have tried a few different ways to get these charts to format the legend the same way, but i have failed.  My goal is to make the legends have the same color scheme and ordering across the different charts.

Example, my chart show the count of projects in each of the following funding statuses - not funded, funded, and unknown.  No matter what I do, the different charts that I am creating, display the different funding statuses in different order with dfferent colors attached to them.  I am using one data source for all charts.  Also, the first chart includes all data in the set while the other 3 apply different filters to the data.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

That link is no longer up, take a look at this blog post: http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/10/25/pie-chart-techniques/

He basically stores the colors in the database and overrides the palette.

I answered a similar question here in more detail: [Want to show legend just once for repeating charts in single page in ssrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134587/want-to-show-legend-just-once-for-repeating-charts-in-single-page-in-ssrs/9145340#9145340)

Comment: And what will happen when your link is no longer up? Please post the relevant part of the answer here and add the link for reference.

Comment: @oers you're absolutely right. Link rot makes both answers useless. I've added a SO link to a similar question I answered.