# Want to show legend just once for repeating charts in single page in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have 8 charts on a single page for 7 days of a week and one for combined. I want to show legend only once at the end of page.I have made visibility of legends for all 8 charts as Hidden.
I have 3 rows and 3 columns of charts in which i have one space (i.e. 9th box in this 3X3 matrix of charts) free to display the legend.
How could I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at last tip on this blog post: 
http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/10/25/pie-chart-techniques/

He overrides the colors from the palette using stored colors in the database.

In Series Properties you select Fill Page and click the Expression. Assuming you store the 6-digit hex value of the color, the expression will be:

```
="#" & Fields!YourColorCode.Value
```

This will ensure the colors will be the same across all charts. To create your "legend" just make a table that displays each field with it's color representation.

There is another question here:
[SSRS 2008 - Uniform Chart Legends for multi-chart report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744856/ssrs-2008-uniform-chart-legends-for-multi-chart-report/9145305#9145305) but the link in the answer no longer works.